# Kendo-Knockout: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kendo' of undefined when using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, jsfiddle

I am using knockout-2.2.1.js, kendo version 2012.3.1114 with kendo-knockout library with version v0.5.0. I get the following error in fiddle in the kendo-knockout library:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property kendo of undefined`

http://jsfiddle.net/wBCdK/21/

In my project everything is fine and I am using the same versions. Am I doing something wrong ? Perhaps somebody provide updated fiddle if the problem is in the versions of the libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like just a problem with the order.  Knockout-Kendo needs to come after Knockout and Kendo.

```
knockout
kendo
knockout-kendo
```

order of knockout and kendo don't matter.

Here is an updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2Qnv7/

Comment: Thanks! Funny but I have almost used some ready templates and never thought the order of the resources have any meaning.